# How to make 'mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum' work in hadoop2.2

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

The number of data node is 6, and I set the value of mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum to 2 in mapred-site.xml.
when I run the MR job, it seems that all the map tasks are running at the same time(it should be 2 map tasks running per node). But it works well in hadoop1.x. What's wrong with my configuration?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @xiaomo   I dont really understand when you said "it seems that all the map tasks are running at the same time" What do you want? Could you be more specific? paste the full log of your Job process?

And I guess you want 2 maps would be excuted in each node .  I don`t think this counld happen if  you only have one job running on the cluster.
But ,If you have 2 jobs running int the cluster , and your mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum is set 2, then you will have 2 maps running per node , one for each job.

Comment: sorry, what i said is not clear enough. I want that each node can run at most 2 map tasks concurrently, and other tasks are pending. But now  all the task are running at one time.

Comment: @xiaomo I think it is impossiable . There be only one piece  of the input file in a node , so Only One map task  run in the node .          And mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum ,this number ,will work when you have more than one job to run.  I remeber this. Maybe we can check the documentation for it.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I misunderstood the meaning of mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum. I should read the documentation and understand it first. Thank you for helping me:-)